# Jquery window scroll on endless scroll fires off too many times

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a bit of an issue I am using an endless scroll and it works however that event fires of many times repeatedly instead of once for example this is my code

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 1) 
                {
                    // database code here
                    alert('times');
                } 
            });
```

Once I get to the bottom of the page that alert box sometimes fires of once or as many as 5 times. As you can see above I also have some code that connects to the database up there and I am thinking that I am also alerting my database up to 5 times . My question is; is there any way to get window scroll to just fire of only 1 time each time the scroll bar is at the bottom like it is supposed to?

Comment: scroll event fires many times a second. Set a flag. Should be easy to find lots of tutorials on how to manage scrolling, also lots of posts on this site

Comment: ok thanks I will do just that.